# How check if a script is running?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am using a custom script (stream.sh) which starts on boot. However, I want to check after every 5 minutes if the script is running. If it is not running, I want to run it again. How can I configure it in crontab or else?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Does your script crash or it exits normally? If it exits normally you can set a PID lockfile in /var/run and remove it at exit and check existence of PID lockfile in /var/run in crontab entry. However, if you want to respawn your script.sh immediately after it exits your init system might be a better tool for the job.

Comment: Define a service in [`systemd`](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) that uses your script. You'll get automatic start/restart/stop, logging, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You may then, if your need is to have it running perpetually, to avoid running it from crontab, run it from inittab with respawn option.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule below mentioned script in crontab

*/5 *  *  *  * /path_of_script

code

```
#!/bin/bash
process=`ps -eaf | grep -i scriptname | grep -iv 'grep' | wc -l`
if [[ $process > 0 ]]
then
echo "script is running"
else
echo "script is not running"
echo "Need to start the script"
sh scriptname
fi
```

Comment: A better way is to have the script create  a `.pid` file in `/var/run` with its own PID. When the script starts it first checks for the PID file and if found check if the process with that pid is still running.